# escape entire lines in XML

Tags: xml, escaping

In C# if you have a string such as "The good\bad", you would get an error because '\b' is not a proper char. SO instead you can do @"The good\bad", which will allow you to print the backslash.

Is there an equivalent technique for XML so that you don't need to put in the special escape characters, such as &

Comment: There is, it's called CDATA.

See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2784183/11683 for an example.

Comment: This might be the only answer, but is there a short form of this?